# Which IP is picked up when using Remote Desktop?

Tags: networking, remote-desktop

This is not a coding question but I can't find a clear answer anywhere so I thought the stackoverflow community will know. Let's say, I'm currently using computer A and running Remote Desktop on Windows to access computer B. From computer B, I sign in to a website. Would the admin for that website be able to tell I was on computer A when I signed in? Or can they only pick up my computer B IP address? I don't know much about networking and remote desktop so any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should ask on [su].

Comment: Thanks. I'll post it on there.

Comment: Everything you do on B happens on B. The fact that keystrokes and mouse clicks are arriving to it over a network cannot propagate to a web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IP will be of computer B. You can think of Remote Desktop as a TV (with which you can interact) - the images from the remote computer are transmitted to your computer, but all actions still happen on the remote computer.

Comment: Thank you. that's very helpful.